# Try number exceeds the max allowed retries

Tags: airflow

With airflow, we set the max number of retries to 2. However, last weekend it happened that it exceeded this max number and crashed our airflow.

I looked into the airflow code itself, but can't seem to find what could have caused this to happen. The airflow logs simply state Try 12 of 2. Anyone any idea how this could happen?

Comment: Can you check the timestamps of each attempt? Were they using the expected `retry_delay`? Have you verified the max `retries` value is set to what you expect on the "Task Details" page? Any chance someone else could've cleared the task so that it would run again (with the same retries)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the following.

1. The incremental logic is flawed as it increased by more than 1 in value
2. The conditional for retries is set to something like if(x==2) but should be coded as if(x>=2)

With other people in code I always check for >= just to make sure that if there is some rogue logic out there that would not properly set the count I'll capture it.